# wildcard usage for a directory displaying filenames in linux?

Tags: ls, wildcards

so one of the questions i have been working on is to display the contents of a directory `files` by using its wildcards do display specific contents, in this case aim using `ls` and the portion that I got lost on is I need to display filenames that stat is `a` but exclude everything that has `aa`. it can however be `ab`.

any hints, ill keep looking and post and answer if i find anything, and any help with usage of wildcards would be great. Thanks

Comment: Err, a "wildcard" glob will be expanded by the shell prior to `ls` even being run, and (unless `zsh` `EXTENDED_GLOB` or such) there's not much you can do with them. Another option would be to pipe the listing to `grep`, but that's not using wildcards.

Comment: typically i used `ls ? * ! []` to figure what filenames to display

Comment: Is this for a real problem, or a challenge, homework, learning exercise? The answer may differ depending on which.

Answer (score 2):

To match on filename that start with `a` but do not contain `aa` anywhere,

with `zsh -o extendedglob`, you'd use the `~` *except* operator:

```
ls -ld a*~*aa*
```

With `bash -O extglob -O failglob`:

```
ls -ld !(!(a*)|*aa*)
```

Answer (score 0):

Doing complicated file globs with multiple conditions in the shell is difficult. It's easier to use `find` for this:

```
find files -maxdepth 1 -name 'a*' ! -name '*aa*' -type f -print
```

This would output the pathnames of any regular file in the directory `files` that start with `a` while not containing the substring `aa`.

To get `ls -l` behaviour, change `-print` to `-ls`.

Answer (score -1):

the answer i found is `ls a[!a]*`

This will allow me to find a word with `a` as first character but nothing with `aa`

Comment: Your glob still won't match the one-letter filename `a`.  I don't know if that's important to you.

Comment: It does exactly what I need it to display a file name that starts with 'a' but not 'aa'

Comment: This would list all names that start with `a` followed by something other than `a`, like `abaa` (which should not be listed).